# Stuck at evaluating $\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \tau(d)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-counting-function

It seems the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the equation $xyz=n$ is given by 
$$\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \tau(d)$$

$\tau$ is the number of divisors function. I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify this sum. Really appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

---

Here is my attempt so far
$$xyz = n$$

$x$ can be any of the factors of $n$ and the product $yz$ will be $n/x$.
Since $yz$ sees all the factors of $n$, the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $xyz=n$ is simply the sum of divisors of the product $yz$.

Edit : Special thanks to @Tryss for identifying an error in the formula. I've fixed it now..

Comment: What is $\tau(n)$ supposed to be?

Comment: I'd say that it is the number of divisors. The formula makes sense.

Comment: @ajotatxe, ah, I'm more accustomed to $\sigma_0(n)$, and reserve $\tau$ for Ramanujan's function, but I was sure that wasn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: Oh sorry! Yes, $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors funciton. I'll update the question.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, there is $3$ solutions to $xyz = n$, so your formula is false. You can't multiply by 2 because there can be permutations that gives the same solutions : you count $ (1,n,1)$ twice

Comment: I see... that is one big error in my work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function
$$f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\tau(d)$$
is multiplicative. That is, $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ whenever $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Let's try to find a formula for powers of primes:

$$f(p^r)=\sum_{d\mid p^r}\tau(d)=\sum_{k=0}^r\tau(p^k)=\sum_{k=0}^r(k+1)=\frac{(r+1)(r+2)}2$$

Then, if the prime factorization of $n$ is
$$n=\prod_{k=1}^sp_k^{t_k}$$
we have that
$$f(n)=2^{-s}\prod_{k=1}^s(t_k+1)(t_k+2)$$

Comment: I'm not sure why the sum $(k+1)$ is equal to $\frac{(r+1)(r+2)}2$, can you enlight me about this result?

Answer (score 4):

Factor $n$ as $p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$. Then every solution is associated with three vectors (the exponents in the factorizations of $x,y,z$) with non-negative integer components and sum given by $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)$. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), it follows that the number of solutions is given by 
$$ \prod_{h=1}^{k}\frac{(\alpha_h+2)(\alpha_h+1)}{2}.$$